# Populating select options button using jquery in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is my jquery,

```
 $('.chosen').change(function () {
        var criteria = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Claims/AddSearchCriteria",
            data: { seacrhCriteria: criteria },
            success: function (response) {
                alert(response);
                var itemToAdd = "<tr><td><select>foreach(var item in response){<option value='' disabled selected style='display:none;'>item</option>}<input type='text'/></select></td></tr>";
                $("#tableForRows").append(itemToAdd);
            }
        });
    });
```

In this I'm sending a variable criteria to controller and getting a list based on the value of variable criteria..
I'm returning this result from controller to jquery using json result, I successfully got the result in success function of jquery, but I want to display the list in the select button, I have used foreach but instead of showing list items it is showing me word "item".
Help me do this...
Thanks in advance...

Comment: what is in your controler?

Comment: Post in your question output of `console.log(response)`.

Comment: Why add `display:none` to each option? And adding an `<input type='text'>` directly inside a `select` will not do what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate in jQuery like this.

Thing you probably are looking after is something like:

```
var $tr = $("<tr><td><select></select></td></tr>"),
    $select = $tr.find('select');

$.each(response, function(i, item){
    $select.append($('<option>'+item+'</option>'));
});
$("#tableForRows").append($tr);
```

Comment: Thanks Kalle, that worked...If I want to add class 'chosen' for select button, like <select class='chosen'>, how do I do that?..i did try this,    var $tr = $("<tr><td><select class='chosen'></select></td></tr>"), but it didn't work...